# R - apply function not work with scale function on additional argument center and scale

Tags: r, matrix, statistics

As we know, the built-in `scale()` function inputs a matrix (or numeric data frame) and computes z-scores for each column. The output from `scale()` is a matrix object with additional attributes called `"scaled:center"` and `"scaled:scale"` that contain, respectively, the means and standard deviations that were used in computing the z-scores.
Now i have a sample data frame named `trees` from `"package:datasets"` on RStudio environment, e.g

```
    > trees
   Girth Height Volume
1    8.3     70   10.3
2    8.6     65   10.3
3    8.8     63   10.2
4   10.5     72   16.4
5   10.7     81   18.8
6   10.8     83   19.7
```

now i need to use the `scale()` function to compute the z-scores of each variable in the `trees` dataset, i try to only work with `scale()` function with additional argument as below, it works perfect

```
test1 <- scale(trees, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)
attributes(test1)
```

You can see the new added attributes based on the optional arguments `center` and `scale` as below:

```
$`scaled:center`
   Girth   Height   Volume 
13.24839 76.00000 30.17097 

$`scaled:scale`
    Girth    Height    Volume 
 3.138139  6.371813 16.437846
```

But when i try `scale` function within `apply` function, the result come out **without** new attributes which suppose to be same as above, please help to figure out why and how to make `scale` function work with `apply`.

```
test2 <- apply(trees, 2, scale, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)
attributes(test2) # No attribute comes out
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can also use `map` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
map(trees, scale, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

`apply` returns output of same dimension as the `MARGIN` used. Use `lapply` instead which returns a list.

```
test2 <- lapply(trees, scale, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)

attributes(test2[[1]])
#$dim
#[1] 31  1

#$`scaled:center`
#[1] 13.25

#$`scaled:scale`
#[1] 3.138
```

Comment: "apply returns output of same dimension as the MARGIN used" as your mention, i guess this is the conflict between apply and scale, yeah, i tried lapply also, that returns as same you suggest, but just try to know why apply not work, thank you for suggestion.

Comment: @Lampard yes, since `apply` returns the output which is of same dimension there is no "place" to store additional attributes. List has the freedom to store additional attributes and uneven data structure.